# SonarQube issue: Method may fail to clean up stream or resource on checked exception

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

The following statement in my code is being red-marked by SonarQube as a critical issue.
    stmt=conn.createStatement();

The exact issue is, "method may fail to clean up java.sql.Statement on checked exception".

Code snippet below:

```
.
.
.
try{
    .
    .
    .

    **stmt=conn.createStatement();**

    .
    .
    .
} catch (SQLException e) {
    ...exception logged... 
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    ...exception logged...
}finally{

    try {
            if(rs !=  null)
            {
                    rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        ...exception logged...
    }

    if(stmt !=  null)
    {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            ...exception logged...
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            ...exception logged...
        }
    }

    if(conn !=  null)
    {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            ...exception logged...              }
    }

}
.
.
.
```

The rule shown by SonarQube is as below:

*Method may fail to clean up stream or resource on checked exception
This method may fail to clean up (close, dispose of) a stream, database object, or other resource requiring an explicit cleanup operation.
In general, if a method opens a stream or other resource, the method should use a try/finally block to ensure that the stream or resource is cleaned up before the method returns.
This bug pattern is essentially the same as the OS_OPEN_STREAM and ODR_OPEN_DATABASE_RESOURCE bug patterns, but is based on a different (and hopefully better) static analysis technique. See Weimer and Necula, Finding and Preventing Run-Time Error Handling Mistakes, for a description of the analysis technique. .
findbugs:OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION_EXCEPTION_EDGE  Sep12 Reliability > Exception handling*

I have closed all the connections, statements and resultsets.
What might be the issue here?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using ? If Java 7, try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Thanks @VinodJayachandran Can you suggest something for Java 6?

Answer (score 0):

From this message **method may fail to clean up java.sql.Statement on checked exception**, my suspect is you are specific exception like NPE or SqlException. Try to catch Exception as a whole and try if it works . Reference as below.

```
try {
        if(rs !=  null)
        {
                rs.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    ...exception logged...
}

if(stmt !=  null)
{
    try {
        stmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        ...exception logged...
    }
}

if(conn !=  null)
{
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...exception logged...              }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @VinodJayachandran but this is also not working.